# Bounded Versus Totally Bounded Sets Definition

Tags: real-analysis

I am given these two definitions for bounded and totally bounded sets but I need some clarification.

Bounded: A set E in a metric space M, d is bounded if there is a real number K and a point q ∈ X such that d(p,q)< K for all p∈E. 
Example: Let x=reals and d the standard metric. E=[0,1)U{-2}. Could you explain why this is so.

Is this saying that for some set(E) that is contained in a metric space M with a distance d defined on that metric space, the set E is bounded if I could pick a point,q, in the set E given, and create an open ball around it with radius K that covers the whole set E. (I am confused about where the X and p comes from as well as why d(p,q)< K.

A set A in a metric space M, d is said to be totally bounded if, given any  >0, there exist finitely many points x<sub>1</sub>,x<sub>2</sub>,...,x<sub>n</sub>∈ M such that A ⊆ U<sup>n</sup><sub>i=1</sub>B(x<sub>i</sub>), where B(x<sub>i</sub>)={x⊆M|d(x,x<sub>i</sub>)<}.
Example:(-2,3]U{7}U[8,9] is totally bounded in the reals. Could you explain why this is so.

Is this saying that for a set, A, contained in the Metric M with a distance, d, defined on it is totally bounded if I could pick multiple points within either the metric space or the set, A, and create multiple open balls with radius epsilon and the union of all those open balls should cover the set A?(In this case I am confused with what B(x<sub>i</sub>)={x⊆M|d(x,x<sub>i</sub>)<} is saying as well as what the radius of these open balls are and why the radius matters.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is kind of right.
$A$ is totally bounded if and only if, given any $\epsilon >0$ (no matter how small), the set $A$ can be covered by **finitely many** balls with radius $\epsilon$.

The importance of the radius lies precisely in that it can be made arbitrarily small; regardless of the size, the cover should still use only finitely many balls.

Comment: Oh I see! But with bounded, there has to be one single ball (does not matter how big or small) so long as it covers the whole set given. Now my follow up question is, does the point chosen have to be in the metric or the set for either bounded or totally bounded or is the placement of the point insignificant? @Fimpellizieri

Comment: It is not significant in either case.

Comment: My last follow up question would be, for the set [0,1)U{-2}, this is bounded because let's say if I picked the point 0 with radius 3, then the set would be completely contained in the ball.  @Fimpellizier

Comment: And for the set (-2,3] U{7}U[8,9]: I could make one of the balls at point  -2 with radius 3 in which would take care of (-2,3], another ball at point 8 with radius 1 which would take care of {7} and [8,9] at the same time (I could have split that up to smaller balls such as one at point 7 with radius one and another ball at point 9 with radius 1 or a bigger ball for the whole problem at let say point 7 with radius 11 and it would suffice) @Fimpellizier

Comment: Yes, $[0,1) \cup \{-2\}$ is a bounded set, and your choice of ball works. It is also totally bounded (can you show it?).

Comment: I can show it with the proof that totally bounded sets in R are bounded but the other way does not hold @Fimpellizieri

Comment: Your choice of balls for $S = (-2,3]\cup\{7\}\cup[8,9]$ does not work to show that it is bounded; you need a single ball. For instance, you can pick $B(0;100)$, the ball centered at $0$ and with radius $100$. If you want to show it is totally bounded, you cannot pick the radius of the balls. You need to show that the condition holds for an arbitrary (but fixed) $\epsilon > 0$.

Comment: Oh right right! So your solution works since you have found one single radius of a ball that would cover the space finitely(in that case one ball one suffice) but even if the ball was smaller and not radius 100, so long as there is a finite number balls of a fixed radius that could be made to cover the space, we are fine! Just to make sure, I am allowed to choose the points to place the ball so that it covers the space and that is the only thing I need to pick multiple of if there needed to be multiple points to cover the space entirely! @Fimpellizieri

Comment: You seem to be confusing the two notions. Please ask precisely one question at a time.

Comment: In terms of totally bounded, the radius has to be fixed for all the balls but the points I choose to place the ball around are something I also control. For the example =(−2,3]∪{7}∪[8,9], I could pick a ball of radius 2 and then the placement of the balls could be {0,1,7,9} and that would cover the whole set , making set  totally bounded, correct? @Fimpellizieri

Comment: Almost correct. The balls are open, so the point $3$ is not covered by your balls. Notice however, that to show something is totally bounded it is not enough to show that you can cover it with balls of some particular radius (in your example, $2$). You must show that no matter how small the radius, you can cover it with finitely many balls.

Comment: Opps yes they are open balls ignore that answer I gave. But now I see, giving one example does not mean anything even if it covers the space because I should be able to show that no matter how small the radius gets, I can cover the set given with a finite number of balls and that would be showing it is totally bounded! A single instance where the set is covered is not enough! Thank you for all your clarifying points. @Fimpellizieri

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to have helped.